# How to position drawable in-between 2 string resources in SpannableStringBuilder without using index number

Tags: java, android, textview, android-drawable, spannablestring

How can a drawable be placed in-between 2 different strings within a SpannableString? Due to varying character lengths in words when read in different languages, I don't want to use integers for index numbers.

```
    TextView txt1 = new TextView(getActivity());
    txt1.setTransformationMethod(null);
    SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    ssb.append(getString(R.string.hello));
    ssb.append(" ");
    ssb.append(" ");
    ssb.append(getString(R.string.world));

    Drawable d1 = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_arrows_leftandright_black);
    d1.setBounds(0, 0, d1.getIntrinsicWidth(), d1.getIntrinsicHeight());
    ImageSpan span1 = new ImageSpan(d1, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
    ssb.setSpan(span1, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    txt1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    txt1.setText(ssb);
```

Comment: Could you want to let your drawable in-between `hello  world`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
    SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    ssb.append(getString(R.string.hello));
    ssb.append(" ");
    ssb.append(" ");
    ssb.append(getString(R.string.world));

    // edited here , add length
    int length = getString(R.string.hello).length();

    Drawable d1 = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_arrows_leftandright_black);
    d1.setBounds(0, 0, d1.getIntrinsicWidth(), d1.getIntrinsicHeight());
    ImageSpan span1 = new ImageSpan(d1, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);

    // edited here , add length to it
    ssb.setSpan(span1, length, length + 2, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

**Note**

This is the length of `String`.

```
    int length = getString(R.string.hello).length();
    int length2 = getString(R.string.world).length();
    int lengthSum = ssb.length();
```

- If `getString(R.string.hello)` was on the left.
      You can use this.

  ```
  ssb.setSpan(span1, length, length + 2, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
  ```

Another way

- You can use this.

  ```
  ssb.setSpan(span1, lengthSum - length2 - 2, lengthSum - length2, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
  ```

Comment: Good luck.I'm glad to help you.